# HTTP запрос выводит [object Object],[object Object]

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, node.js, http

Всем доброго времени суток )
у меня есть файл medusa.json он генерируется от парсера с новосного сайта,
хочу вывести информацию на сайт визуально с JSON файла

делаю запрос

```
fetch('medusa.json')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    alert(data);
  });
```

возвращает

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]....

как переобразовать его  ?

сам JSON выглядит так

```
[{
    "title": "В Луцке",
    "time": "час назад",
    "link": "https://meduza.io/news/20...",
    "img": null
}, {
    "title": "Из.....
```

делал еще таким образом

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    let obj = myObj;
    alert(obj)
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "medusa.json", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

так же выводит

```
[object Object],[object Object]..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//alert(data);
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

---

```
alert(data[0].time);

data.forEach(item => console.log(item.time));
```

Comment: я так понимаю оно делает из JSON строку, но как переобразовать в JS обект, чтобы я мог к примеру вывести исключительно  "time": "час назад"

Comment: @ike77 `alert(data[0].time);`

Comment: спасибо большое)